# SSRS Multiple Dataset Errors

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a simple SSRS report that displays data from one table. What I want to do is have a distinct list from that table displayed in a drop down list for the user to select. If I only use one dataset I can get it to display, but it displays values from the column multiple times.

Example

```
Bob
Bob
Bob
Cathy
Cathy
```

If I create a second dataset that will list distinct values I get the following error message:

> *An Error occurred during local report processing. The definition of the report is invalid. The Variable expression for the report 'body' refers directly to the field without specifying a dataset aggregate. When the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.*

I"m trying to follow the example I found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337400.aspx

The second dataset is only for the parameter list. I don't understand why it's causing problems with the actual report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible to tell exactly where without the report definition, but there is an item on the report that is referencing a field or Dataset, and was implicitly using the only Dataset present in the report, but now doesn't know which Dataset to use once more than one is added to the report.

For example, when you create a table you can set a Dataset associated with it. If this is not set and there is only one Dataset, it doesn't matter as it will take the only one available. Once you add a new Dataset, the table doesn't know which one to use and you'll get the error you're seeing.

Another way to get the error is specifying a field in an expression, e.g. in a TextBox in the report somewhere without specifying the scope; just set the scope to a particular Dataset e.g. if you have:

```
=Count(Fields!name.Value)
```

change this to:

```
=Count(Fields!name.Value, "DatasetToUse")
```

If you've only got one Dataset the first expression will run fine by using the only one available, but once you add another it won't know which to use and it will error.

Comment: All of my fields are =(Fields!item.Value, "DataSet1") I'm not using any aggregates in the report at all. Also if I remove any reference to the second dataset in the report it still won't run. For the report definition, do you want the XML?

Comment: If the expression is in a Tablix, remove the scope reference and set the Dataset at the Tablix level. If the expression is out of a Tablix, make sure it's an aggregate function, e.g. First() or Count() with the scope set to the appropriate Dataset.

Comment: I did some work on it over the weekend and when I rebuilt the report in SQL 2008 (it was R2 previously) it worked fine. Can you think of anything in 2008 R2 SSRS that would be that different from vanilla 2008?

Comment: No, I suspect what happened is that when you rebuilt it something was just different enough to prevent the error from occurring. For these situations (i.e. some random error that I can't easily see) I generally copy the report and start deleting items until it works - then add items back in until I see exactly what's causing it. Anyway, glad it's working for you!

Comment: Me too, I'll give you credit for the answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in the query (SQL) you should add `DISTINCT` clause at the beginning, that way, you will get only one record per value. Check out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 0):

Double click the Dataset which contains that field.
Go to fields on the left and delete that field.
Add new field by clicking Add -> Query Field.
Just type in the name of the new field under field name and field source.

It happens when you have added a field by selecting "Calculated Field" instead of "Query Field" from Dataset Fields list tab.

Cheers,
Ahmed Latif