# Multiple Datasets in One SSRS

Tags: c#, oracle, reporting-services, rdlc

I cannot use First() because I have multiple data to return.

I cannot use Lookup() because I don't know what data to look for.

Any other workaround? or the only way is I have to change my query?

Comment: This is unclear what you are trying to do. Can you please add some specific details about your problem?

Comment: I'm trying to use multiple datasets in a ssrs.

Comment: Yes, I got that from the title. However, how are you trying to do this, what does your data look like, how does it relate together and what is the output you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Multiple Dataset Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267848/ssrs-multiple-dataset-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. But since you mention `First()` you are probably trying to include a data from dataset1(with multiple data) to a table where that table is using dataset2(with multiple data).  `First()` here is not possible since it will only take the first data.

If your data(multiple data) is just numbers you could use

```
=SUM(Fields!Field.Value, "dataset1")
```

to sum your data from another dataset but if your data is not a number I advice you create another query to handle your data output. Its much easier to join tables in there. Then create new dataset for that query. This will make your life easier.

Comment: Finally, someone who understand :) Yes, I ended up changing my query instead rather than using multiple datasets. The data are numbers but I need to display then one by one so I can't use SUM().